# e.target.name giving undefined error on submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

here's the error I get back when I click save, once I refresh the edit displays correctly in the browser

"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

this error is in regards to my "handleChange" function inside of my "editSetup" component. Here's the full code for the component

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '../context/UserContext';

import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

function EditSetup({setup, isEdit, setIsEdit}) {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const {name, description, photo, genre, id} = setup;

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: name,
    description: description,
    photo: photo,
    genre: genre
  });


  function handleChange(e) {
    console.log('e',e)
    setFormData({...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  function handleEditSetup(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(`/setups/${id}`, {
      method: "PATCH",
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      handleChange(data)
    })
  }

  

  return (
    <Container>
    <Form onSubmit={handleEditSetup}>
      <Form.Label>Name:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="name"
        value={formData.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Form.Label>Description:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        as="textarea"
        rows={3}
        type="text"
        name="description"
        value={formData.description}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Form.Label>Photo:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="photo"
        value={formData.photo}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Form.Label>Genre:</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control
        type="text"
        name="genre"
        value={formData.genre}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Button variant="success" type="submit">
        Save
      </Button>
    </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default EditSetup
```

i've tried changing the "name" attribute in my form but it didn't help

Comment: that suggests `e.target` is undefined - which is probably when you call it like that `.then(data => {
      handleChange(data)
    })` - `data` is unlikely to be an `Event`

Comment: instead of `console.log('e',e)` try `console.log({e})` - not an answer, just a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

As `@Jaromanda X` suggested in his comment, `handleChange` is an event handler, i.e., it expects an event as an argument, however you are passing a plain object.
You just need to update the data after the request like so:

```js
.then(data => {
  setFormData(data)
})
```

However, depending on the response, it may contain some metadata, or something that's not relevant to the formData object. A bit cleaner solution would be to do this:

```js
.then(data => {
  const { name, description, photo, genre } = data
  setFormData({name, description, photo, genre})
})
```